# How do I get an image w/ the exact size in pixels, when using bbox_inches='tight' in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot graphs to an exact resolution (e.g. 800x600), but when using `bbox_inches='tight`' the plots are not at full resolution, they are smaller.
I can manually set the image size in inches to about (9.2, 6.5), which results in 799 x 601, but I hope there is a better solution. Can you set `bbox_inches='tight'` before adjusting the size?

```
import matplotlib as mlp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = y = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
plt.plot(x, y, label='my function')
plt.title('title')
ax.set_xlabel('xAxis')
ax.set_ylabel('yAxis')

#print fig.get_size_inches()
#fig.set_size_inches(9.2, 6.5)

plt.savefig('exact_size_test.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100)
```

https://img707.imageshack.us/img707/2192/exactsizetest.png

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Comment: Yes 'fig__tight_layout()' works perfect, so I finally accepted it (better late than never :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `tight_layout`[(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.tight_layout) before calling `savefig`

```
import matplotlib as mlp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = y = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
plt.plot(x, y, label='my function')
plt.title('title')
ax.set_xlabel('xAxis')
ax.set_ylabel('yAxis')

#print fig.get_size_inches()
fig.set_size_inches(8, 6, forward=True)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('exact_size_test.png', dpi=100)
```

Comment: thx again for the help, that's what I was looking for

but I have a problem, when the legend is outside the plot
`plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left')`

I know I can fix this by adding this parameter
`bbox_extra_artists=(fig.get_axes()[0].get_legend(),)`

to plt.savefig().
But the legend gets cut off, if I apply the tight_layout before announcing the extra artists.

I didn't find any option to set bbox_extra_artists outside of savefig. I know I can shrink the plot's width to fit the legend, but I want to keep it as dynamic as possible.

Comment: What version of MPL are you using?  This is something that I think has been addressed recently (tight-layout is still newish).

Comment: I'm using MPL version 1.2.0. Here is an example of what it looks like:  
[link](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/2192/exactsizetest.png)  
  
Changing the backend from 'TkAgg' to 'Agg' had no effect.